# second class's style not over-ruling previous class's styles as expected

Tags: html, css

In these styles I have three class: `.gen-btn`, `.login_selection_button`, and `.gen-btn-disabled`. I would like that the button with the class `.gen-btn-disabled` never changes styles based on `:active` or `:hover`. I have it set up in my stylesheet as the last style on the page, and it is written in the input's class-declaration as the last item.

Currently I have `gen-btn-disabled` set so that it's normal state, active state, and hover state are the same as the style as `gen-btn`. That is to say, I would like it always to keep the same styles as `gen-btn` has in its normal state.

However it seems redundant, and like I should just be able to put it at the top of the sheet, right next to `gen-btn`, since it is the last style declared on the input (ie: `<input type="button" id="login_webview" class="gen-btn login_selection_button gen-btn-disabled" value="&rarr;" />​`)

gen-btn-disabled still takes all the styles from active and hover and focus. I don't understand what I've done wrong. Thanks for looking!

http://jsfiddle.net/loren_hibbard/vax98/3/

Comment: You forgot to disable `box-shadow` in `gen-btn-disabled`, it's still getting applied.

Comment: @Zeta you should make that an answer. I think it's more correct than Kai Qing's answer.

Comment: @Zeta Why would I want to disable the box shadow. I just want it to have the same box shadow as `gen-btn`. Will disabling it make `gen-btn-disabled` keep the `gen-btn` box shadow style when `gen-btn-disabled` is `:active`? Thanks!

Comment: Well, you change it in `.gen-btn:hover`, you have to address this. @Colleen: I'm way to tired for an appropriate answer, feel free to gain the reputation. Imaginary bonus if you use the HTML `disabled` attribute with `.gen-btn[disabled]` and `.gen-btn:not([disabled])`.

Comment: looks like from your question and your css rules that you didn't want the shadow-- that you wanted the `gen-btn-disabled` to look the same all the time.

Comment: @Colleen Well, I said `Currently I have it set so that it's normal state, active state, and hover state are the same as the style as gen-btn.` which isn't very clear, you're right. I'll edit it! Thanks!

Comment: good point from Zeta: OP, you probably want to be using the html attribute `disabled` instead of a "disabled" class. Would make this business much easier.

Comment: @Colleen Yes! But it wasn't disabling the styles from active and hover when I had tried that earlier, so I was sort of trying to engineer my own. Perhaps `disabled="disabled"` doesn't work with this css3 stuff, or perhaps I was just using it wrong :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're assuming that lower placement in the stylesheet means higher priority. In CSS, the more specific the selector, the higher priority. There are many other factors that determine priority, but in your case this should work -

Just use a more specific selector for the disabled class:

```
input[type="button"].login_selection_button.gen-btn-disabled{
    /* disabled styles here */
}
```

And as Zeta pointed out, applying specific styles generically can lead to unwanted effects. I suppose my observation was more that the padding and font sizes were different and by selectors, the first declaration would take priority no matter where the disabled style was defined.

Comment: I was under the impression that override rules went specificity -> position in style sheet. I.e. that 2 rules with the same level of specificity would then default to order in the stylesheet to determine which got applied.

Comment: If equal, yes. But in his example they are not equal because the one above targets more specific because it includes the input selector. This is an OK article on the priorities. Not the best example, but suitable: http://monc.se/kitchen/38/cascading-order-and-inheritance-in-css

Comment: @Colleen: that's correct. Lower placement *does* mean higher priority, *assuming* specificity is the same.

Comment: @daGUY the specificity *IS* the same... what's going on here, which isn't clearly articulated by Kai Qing, is that styles are getting combined because the specificity is the same.

Comment: @colleen - I don't think the specificity is the same because of this: input[type="button"].login_selection_button declared 2 positions above the disabled one. That one would keep the padding and font size the same. Zeta's is still correct too though. The basic idea is that he just needs a little cleaning and organizing.